How to modify a STRUCT type column?
There is a table with name newtest and the column name is source of type struct<name:string, size:bigint>.
I want to update/modify this struct type to struct<name:string, size:bigint, index:bigint>
How can I alter/modify source column, which is mentioned above.
Tried with the below sql query it is not working:
ALTER TABLE newtest MODIFY COLUMN source STRUCT<name: STRING, size: bigint, index:bigint>


Assuming, you're using a Delta table, you can modify the struct column as below:
ALTER TABLE newtest ADD COLUMNS (source.index bigint AFTER size)


Thanks This is working, we can also Drop STRUCT Columns with below SQL Syntax
ALTER TABLE newtest ADD COLUMNS (source.index bigint AFTER size)


ALTER TABLE newtest DROP COLUMNS (source.raw)

